Create grouped indicator of observations with the same value in R
I have a bit of specific question.
I have a dataset that looks like this in R:
     name   person_id  year municipality_id
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 Brown        654  2000               1
 2 Brown        781  2000               1
 3 James       2531  2000               1
 4 Smith       2187  2000               1
 5 Smith          6  2000               1
 6 White         22  2000              45
 7 Colgan       100  2000              45
 8 Brown      45123  2000              45
 9 Smith         11  2000              45
10 Smith          9  2000              45
11 Brown        654  2004               1
12 Brown       1641  2004               1
13 James       2531  2004               1
14 Smith       2187  2004               1
15 Smith        450  2004               1
16 White         42  2004              45
17 Colgan       100  2004              45
18 Brown      45123  2004              45
19 Smith         11  2004              45
20 Smith      86573  2004              45
21 Brown        654  2008               1
22 Brown       1641  2008               1
23 James       2531  2008               1
24 Smith       2187  2008               1
25 Smith        450  2008               1
26 White         42  2008              45
27 Colgan       100  2008              45
28 Brown      45123  2008              45
29 Smith         11  2008              45
30 Smith      86573  2008              45

What I want is to know how many different people in each municipality have the same name as each of these in the same or previous year.
Put differently, I want is to create a column (n_same) that gives the number of rows, within each group municipality_id, that have the same value of name, but different person_id in the same or previous years. And then a column that takes the value of 0/1 depending on whether n_same is == 0 (value of 0) or not (1).
The outcome would be basically be something like this:
      name   person_id  year municipality_id n_same dummy
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Brown        654  2000               1      1     1
 2 Brown        781  2000               1      1     1
 3 James       2531  2000               1      0     0
 4 Smith       2187  2000               1      1     1
 5 Smith          6  2000               1      1     1
 6 White         22  2000              45      0     0
 7 Colgan       100  2000              45      0     0
 8 Brown      45123  2000              45      0     0
 9 Smith         11  2000              45      1     1
10 Smith          9  2000              45      1     1
11 Brown        654  2004               1      2     1
12 Brown       1641  2004               1      2     1
13 James       2531  2004               1      0     0
14 Smith       2187  2004               1      2     1
15 Smith        450  2004               1      2     1
16 White         42  2004              45      1     1
17 Colgan       100  2004              45      0     0
18 Brown      45123  2004              45      0     0
19 Smith         11  2004              45      2     1
20 Smith      86573  2004              45      2     1
21 Brown        654  2008               1      2     1
22 Brown       1641  2008               1      2     1
23 James       2531  2008               1      0     0
24 Smith       2187  2008               1      2     1
25 Smith        450  2008               1      2     1
26 White         42  2008              45      1     1
27 Colgan       100  2008              45      0     0
28 Brown      45123  2008              45      0     0
29 Smith         11  2008              45      2     1
30 Smith      86573  2008              45      2     1

Have been trying a bunch of different things on this and can't really get it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

I think I have an answer, but it doesn't match your output--but based on my understanding of your request, my answer is right. If we look at the name = Brown rows in municipality_id = 1, then on rows 1, 2 I agree n_same = 1, on row 11 we've entered 2004, and I agree that n_same = 2 as we have a new Brown on row 12. But why does n_same = 3 on row 12? There are only 3 distinct person_ids so far (year <= 2004) for name = Brown and municipality_id = 1: they are 654 on rows 1 and 11, 781 on row 2, and 1641 on row 12. With 3 distinct values, there are 2 "other" values, right?

I need to step away from the computer for a few hours, so I'll post my answer as-is. If my understanding of the problem is incorrect, hopefully it's at least useful.

Yes, you're right! That was my mistake, sorry. I corrected it now!

This sorts the data for ease of inspection--it does require that the data is sorted by year, at least within municipality groups. After sorting, we get the cumulative count of unique person_ids within each municipality and name, then we take n_same to be 1 less than the max number of our cumulative count, adding year to the grouping values.
The cum_distinct column can be dropped of course, I just leave it in to show better how the answer works.
df |>
  arrange(municipality_id, name, year, person_id) |>
  mutate(
    cum_distinct = cumsum(!duplicated(person_id)),
    .by = c(municipality_id, name)
  ) |>
  mutate(
    n_same = max(cum_distinct) - 1,
    .by = c(name, year, municipality_id)
  )
#      name person_id year municipality_id cum_distinct n_same
# 1   Brown       654 2000               1            1      1
# 2   Brown       781 2000               1            2      1
# 11  Brown       654 2004               1            2      2
# 12  Brown      1641 2004               1            3      2
# 21  Brown       654 2008               1            3      2
# 22  Brown      1641 2008               1            3      2
# 3   James      2531 2000               1            1      0
# 13  James      2531 2004               1            1      0
# 23  James      2531 2008               1            1      0
# 5   Smith         6 2000               1            1      1
# 4   Smith      2187 2000               1            2      1
# 15  Smith       450 2004               1            3      2
# 14  Smith      2187 2004               1            3      2
# 25  Smith       450 2008               1            3      2
# 24  Smith      2187 2008               1            3      2
# 8   Brown     45123 2000              45            1      0
# 18  Brown     45123 2004              45            1      0
# 28  Brown     45123 2008              45            1      0
# 7  Colgan       100 2000              45            1      0
# 17 Colgan       100 2004              45            1      0
# 27 Colgan       100 2008              45            1      0
# 10  Smith         9 2000              45            1      1
# 9   Smith        11 2000              45            2      1
# 19  Smith        11 2004              45            2      2
# 20  Smith     86573 2004              45            3      2
# 29  Smith        11 2008              45            3      2
# 30  Smith     86573 2008              45            3      2
# 6   White        22 2000              45            1      0
# 16  White        42 2004              45            2      1
# 26  White        42 2008              45            2      1


Using this data:
df = read.table(text = '     name   person_id  year municipality_id
 1 Brown        654  2000               1
 2 Brown        781  2000               1
 3 James       2531  2000               1
 4 Smith       2187  2000               1
 5 Smith          6  2000               1
 6 White         22  2000              45
 7 Colgan       100  2000              45
 8 Brown      45123  2000              45
 9 Smith         11  2000              45
10 Smith          9  2000              45
11 Brown        654  2004               1
12 Brown       1641  2004               1
13 James       2531  2004               1
14 Smith       2187  2004               1
15 Smith        450  2004               1
16 White         42  2004              45
17 Colgan       100  2004              45
18 Brown      45123  2004              45
19 Smith         11  2004              45
20 Smith      86573  2004              45
21 Brown        654  2008               1
22 Brown       1641  2008               1
23 James       2531  2008               1
24 Smith       2187  2008               1
25 Smith        450  2008               1
26 White         42  2008              45
27 Colgan       100  2008              45
28 Brown      45123  2008              45
29 Smith         11  2008              45
30 Smith      86573  2008              45', header = T)


This does it. Amazing, thank you!
